# jQuery mouse over menu and animate position element behind

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery equivalent to provide the same functionality as [here](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/sliding-javascript-menu-highlight-1kb/)?

JavaScript

```
var menuSlider=function(){
var m,e,g,s,q,i; e=[]; q=8; i=8;
return{
    init:function(j,k){
        m=document.getElementById(j); e=m.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var i,l,w,p; i=0; l=e.length;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var c,v; c=e[i]; v=c.value; if(v==1){s=c; w=c.offsetWidth; p=c.offsetLeft}
            c.onmouseover=function(){menuSlider.mo(this)}; c.onmouseout=function(){menuSlider.mo(s)};
        }
        g=document.getElementById(k); g.style.width=w+'px'; g.style.left=p+'px';
    },
    mo:function(d){
        clearInterval(m.tm);
        var el,ew; el=parseInt(d.offsetLeft); ew=parseInt(d.offsetWidth);
        m.tm=setInterval(function(){menuSlider.mv(el,ew)},i);
    },
    mv:function(el,ew){
        var l,w; l=parseInt(g.offsetLeft); w=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);
        if(l!=el||w!=ew){
            if(l!=el){var ld,lr,li; ld=(l>el)?-1:1; lr=Math.abs(el-l); li=(lr<q)?ld*lr:ld*q; g.style.left=(l+li)+'px'}
            if(w!=ew){var wd,wr,wi; wd=(w>ew)?-1:1; wr=Math.abs(ew-w); wi=(wr<q)?wd*wr:wd*q; g.style.width=(w+wi)+'px'}
        }else{clearInterval(m.tm)}
}};}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes to mind: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: Thanks pointed me in the right direrction, sadly I had a problem using the latest jquery with the plugin you mention instead I found this: http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos.php